# gradle project dependencies using ant files to build

Tags: ant, build, gradle

We have a custom build application that was built and leverages ant.
This application, call it Bob reads an xml file to understand the interproject dependencies.

I have the following project *file/directory* structure.

```
--root
|--P1
|--P2
|--P3
|--P4
```

Each project (except root) has a build.xml file.
So Bob's interproject dependency xml file might look as follows:

```
 <project name="P1">
 </project>

 <project name="P2">
  <dependencies>
    <dependsOn name="P1"/>
  </dependencies>
 </project>

 <project name="P3">
  <dependencies>
    <dependsOn name="P2"/>    
  </dependencies>
 </project>

 <project name="P4">
  <dependencies>
    <dependsOn name="P2"/>    
    </dependencies>
 </project>

</projects>
```

So the dependency tree as you can see would look like so

```
--root
  |P1
    |--P2
       |--P3
       |--P4
```

To build each project with ant you simply invoke the build target. If you tell Bob to build P3 it knows to invoke ant for each project in order P1, P2 then P3.

What is the simplest way to use Gradle's ant.importBuild 'builder.xml' and define the above project structure so that the build order is always right?

I do not want to restructure the directories to make this work please.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to define a multi-project Gradle build, and wire the Ant targets (which become Gradle tasks after import) as needed. However, you would end up with a legacy Gradle build that resembles your legacy Ant build and misses out on most of Gradle's advantages. You are much more likely to achieve a good and lasting result if you bite the bullet and port the build to Gradle. The ported build could still occasionally reuse Ant tasks where truly needed, but should not import any Ant scripts.

Comment: So let's say each ant build file in each project contains a single target called "build". How would I get gradle to call this target on P1 before it does P2 and there after P3 and P4? Doing a full port is not on the cards right now. Management here like to nibble their bullets before they bite them :)

Comment: You can't easily run all the tasks in project X before any of the tasks in Y, and it's also the wrong thing to do. Instead, you'll have to model the task dependencies individually, e.g. `compile.dependsOn(":otherProject:jar")`. However, this effort will be somewhat obsolete once you truly port the build.

Comment: I understand that there are dependencies between tasks such as compiling before you jar it for instance, but how do you express dependencies between projects?

Comment: See my previous comment. For further information, see the "multi-project builds" chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: To clarify, all execution dependencies are between tasks, not between projects. Even something like `dependencies { compile project(":other") }` ultimately gets translated to task dependencies such as `compileJava.dependsOn(":other:jar")`, but this notation is mostly useful for idiomatic builds.

Comment: So if my ant target is called build could I have a project dependency in P1 such as: `dependencies { build project(":P1")`